# Unreachable Code Detected?

Tags: c#

I am getting this rediculous error "unreachablecode detected" and clearly everything in in proper visibiliity...

Here is the code ..

```
int lastAppNum = 0;

//load the xml document            
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(GlobalVars.strXMLPath);

//add a app node
XmlNode newApp = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "app", null);

//add the app number - this will be used in order to easily identify the app details (used for overwriting/saving)
XmlAttribute newNum = xdoc.CreateAttribute("num");

//in order to create a new number - search the last num and add one to it 
foreach (XmlNode xmlAppChild in xdoc.ChildNodes)
{         
    //if there are existing child nodes
    if (true)
    {                   
        //get the last childs num attribute
        lastAppNum = Convert.ToInt32(xmlAppChild.LastChild.Attributes["num"].Value);

        //add +1 to the last app num
        lastAppNum++;

        //add the new value to the attribute
        newNum.InnerText = lastAppNum.ToString();

        break;

    }else{
        //if there isnt an existing child node - set the num to 1
        lastAppNum = 1; <<where the error happens
        newNum.InnerText = lastAppNum.ToString();
        break;

    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea of whats going on ? I thought perhaps it was the lack of a "break" so i threw two in here (i saw on a form thats what a solution was) but either way it doesnt matter and the error is still happening. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: `if(true)` will probably always be `true` :)

Comment: @user3302467: Unreachable code is not an error if you set the warning level right. It's more a warning to the user that you probably wrote something that was not intended.

Comment: Isn't that what all warnings are? And why they should all be treated as errors?

Comment: Looks like you need to change `if (true)` to a condition that has the same meaning as this: `if there are existing child nodes`

Answer (score 10):

You have `if (true)` - was there some condition you actually wanted to test here?

```
if (true)
{
    // this code will always run
}
else
{
    // this code will never run
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`else` condition will never run since you have `if (true)`

i think based on your comments, you need to change the implimentation as below

```
if(xdoc.HasChildNodes)
{
    foreach (XmlNode xmlAppChild in xdoc.ChildNodes)
    {         

        //if there are existing child nodes                
        //get the last childs num attribute
        lastAppNum = Convert.ToInt32(xmlAppChild.LastChild.Attributes["num"].Value);

        //add +1 to the last app num
        lastAppNum++;

        //add the new value to the attribute
        newNum.InnerText = lastAppNum.ToString();

    }
}else
{

    //if there isnt an existing child node - set the num to 1
    lastAppNum = 1; 
    newNum.InnerText = lastAppNum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code

```
  if (true)
```

will always be executed and there is no chance to else condition be executed.

Comment: ohh that makes sense. Yeah i forgot to throw a conditional statment in there. Whoops!